# OnClick Redirect

Tags: javascript, html

i have a bootstrap button and i want redirect onclick. but when click nothing happens

```
                    <button class="btn btn-option navbar-btn" onclick="location.href='https://stackoverflow.com/';">Enter Class</button>
```

i also tried location href and call a separate function like this

```
                    <button class="btn btn-option navbar-btn" onclick="GoHome()">Enter</button>
function GoHome(){window.location = myurl; }
```

and if i use alert or something else onclick, it works fine but i cant redirect to another page

Answer (score 1):

It works. Here is demo

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" onclick="location.href='https://stackoverflow.com/';">Enter Class</button>
```